# What is the difference between applying a margin to a span element within a div tag and applying a margin within a div tag?

Tags: html, css

```css
.case1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.case2 span {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="case1">
  <span>something</span>
</div>
<div class="case2">
  <span>something</span>
</div>
```

If apply css as follows, the result you see on the screen is the same. So, which of the two methods is best practice and why?

- thx answers. If it is a p element and not a span element, the result is likely to be the same. What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 4):

`<div>`'s and `<p>`'s for example are [Block Level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements that can take up margin on all sides. `<span>`'s cannot as it's an [Inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) that takes up margins horizontally only.

From [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties):

> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The
> 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while
> the other margin properties only set their respective side. These
> properties apply to all elements, but vertical margins will not have
> any effect on non-replaced inline elements.

You can set `display: inline-block;` on your `span` to make it block-level.

```css
.case1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.case2 span {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px; /* margin doesn't work */
  color: hotpink;
}

.case3 span {
  display: inline-block; /* made it block-level, margin works */
  margin-top: 40px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="case1">
  <span>something</span>
</div>


<div class="case2">
  <span>something</span>
</div>

<div class="case3">
  <span>something</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thx! could you answer my extra question?

Comment: "If it is a p element and not a span element, the result is likely to be the same." this one? It works as expected because it is block-level. https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/q1xby7st/2/

Answer (score 3):

In any case you'd prefer to use case 1 because `case 2`doesn't work if there are other elements in the `<div>`

```css
p{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.case1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.case2 span {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="case1">
  <span>something</span>
    <p>
  test
  </p>
</div>

<div class="case2">
  <span>something</span>
  <p>
  test1
  </p>
</div>

<p>
test2
</p>
```

As you can see there is no separation between `test1` and `test2` because `case2` doesn't affect it. But there's a sepration between `test` and the `something` from `case 2`

Answer (score 3):

By architecture, the styles of the span tag are still children of the parent div and not all children are equal to the parent, a clear example is:
If I have a parent div with style color:#333, all the children, including the span ones, will inherit this color. Otherwise, if the child wants another color, be it span or another label, you use the second option. This applies even in margins.